# php Login Form and my sql connection

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mysql

I have create one form which 'login action button form' in as under

```
<?php

include "dbconnect.php";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "select * from login where username='$username' AND password='$password'";
// var_dump($result);

$result =  mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
    header("location:fill-detail.php");
}
else 
{
    echo 'Sorry, Wrong ID and Password';
}

?>
```

I have used ver_dump the result array also display but output given **Warning:** mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line of code and see what error is output for you

```
$result =  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `mysql_error($connection)` will return you a friendly message, which is causing this issue.

Common errors in these cases(as your query is quiet simple) are misspelled column names, choosing the wrong table..

Points to be noted :

- **mysql_()** are deprecated, you should use **mysqli_()** or **PDO**.
- You need to escape the data and sanitize it before dealing with any type of query
- You are using `*` to select all columns which is not a good practice, always fetch the relevant columns only
- THIS IS IMPORTANT ONE - HASH YOUR PASSWORDS